How to block burp suite requests in an ASP.NET 4.8 Web API or ASP.NET Core Web API
I'm currently working on an ASP.NET 4.8 Web API and ASP.NET Core. I've noticed that our application is potentially vulnerable to security testing tools like Burp Suite, which could be used to exploit weaknesses or scrape data from the API. I'm looking for guidance on how to effectively block or mitigate requests coming from Burp Suite or similar tools.
Current Setup:

Framework: ASP.NET 4.8 Web API
Hosting Environment: Virtual Machine (VM) or AKS
Security concerns: preventing unauthorized or malicious access to the API, specifically from tools like Burp Suite.

Steps taken so far: server side validation for each UI field, which is a tedious job

Perhaps using an API key? depending of the use for the API an OAuth 2.0 authentification... we need more info on the environment

1st priority is to act on the vulnerabilities reported by Burp Suite.   To block or help mitigate actual malicious probes/requests you might consider a reverse proxy that specializes in that sort of thing.  To block unauthorized requests, you should build in user authentication/authorization.

We can add authorization mechanism into your API so that anonymous requests are forbidden, but it doesn't prevent malicious attack requests from accessing the server, it just prevents these requests getting data from your API. So that we also need to set whitelist and blacklist. By the way, we might try to find an out-of-box services to do the task so that we don't need to manage it by ourselves.

@browsermator we already have authentication/authorisation added to our application

The security team is maliciously testinh for UI values like User id or any dropdown values,which results in 200OK response , their expectation is to have 404 not found or unauthorised access

Also we cant block the security team from testing our application since they are authorised users, we need to block the requests from manipulating any UI values

UI meaning front-end?  That sounds like you are trusting the client.  You should not.  (and definitely make sure you aren't vulnerable to over-posting...)

I'm thinking what's needed here is just more communication between you and the pen-testers.  They should be able to give you a more detailed response on how to fix your security problems and bugs.

You need read the request
userAgent = Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
if (userAgent.Contains("Mozilla/5.0"))
{
    // Request is likely from a browser
}
else
{
    // Request is likely from a testing tool or other client
}

you can discard request


that's woe-fully inadequate for blocking malicious requests/probes and will probably block plenty of regular users/devices as well.
